# Dagster -Execute an @Op only when all parallel executions are finished(DynamicOutput)

Tags: dagster

I have a problem that in fact I am not able to solve in dagster.

I have the following configuration:

I have step 1 where I get the data from an endpoint

step 2 gets a list of customers dynamically:

step 3 is the database update with the response from step 1, for each customer from step 2, but in parallel.

before calling step 3, I have a function that serves to create DynamicOutput for each client of step 2, with the name "parallelize_clients "so that when it is invoked, it parallelizes the update processes of step_3 and finally I have a graph to join operations.

```
@op()
def step_1_get_response():
    return {'exemple': 'data'}

@op()
def step_2_get_client_list():
    return ['client_1', 'client_2', 'client_3'] #the number of customers is dynamic.

@op(out=DynamicOut())
def parallelize_clients(context, client_list):
    for client in client_list:
        yield DynamicOutput(client, mapping_key=str(client))


@op()
def step_3_update_database_cliente(response, client):
    ...OPERATION UPDATE IN DATABASE CLIENT

@graph()
def job_exemple_graph():
    response = step_1_get_response()
    clients_list = step_2_get_client_list()
    clients = parallelize_clients(clients_list)
    #run the functions in parallel
    clients.map(lambda client: step_3_update_database_cliente(response, client))
```

According to the documentation, an @Op starts as soon as its dependencies are fulfilled, and in the case of Ops that have no dependency, they are executed instantly, without having an exact order of execution. Example: My step1 and step2 have no dependencies, so both are running in parallel automatically. After the clients return, the "parallelize_clients()" function is executed, and finally, I have a map in the graph that dynamically creates several executions according to the amount of client(DynamicOutput)

[image]

So far it works, and everything is fine. Here's the problem. I need to execute a specific function only when step3 is completely finished, and as it is created dynamically, several executions are generated in parallel, however, I am not able to control to execute a function only when all these executions in parallel are finished.

in the graph I tried to put the call to an op "exemplolaststep() step_4" at the end, however, step 4 is executed together with "step1" and "step2", and I really wanted step4 to only execute after step3, but not I can somehow get this to work. Could someone help me?

[image]

I tried to create a fake dependency with

```
@op(ins={"start": In(Nothing)})
def step_4():
    pass
```

and in the graph, when calling the operations, I tried to execute the map call inside the step_4() function call; Example

```
@graph()
def job_exemple_graph():
    response = step_1_get_response()
    clients_list = step_2_get_client_list()
    clients = parallelize_clients(clients_list)
    #run the functions in parallel
    step_4(start=clients.map(lambda client: step_3_update_database_cliente(response, client)))
```

I have tried other approaches as well, however, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a `.collect()` call on the mapped function in your graph, to indicate that all the parallel operations should join before moving on. Something like

```py
@graph()
def job_exemple_graph():
    response = step_1_get_response()
    clients_list = step_2_get_client_list()
    clients = parallelize_clients(clients_list)
    # run the functions in parallel
    step_4(
        start=clients.map(
            lambda client: step_3_update_database_cliente(response, client)
        ).collect()
    )
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much, my life for sure. I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now. And note, it's my second question here on stackoverflow and the second one you answer, so much so that this problem is an extension of the initial solution where you helped me earlier. Again, thank you very much, I already tested it and it worked very well.

Comment: @CristianoCardosodosSantos - no worries at all, it's all about the community. the Dagster Slack channel is also a great place to get help when you need it - https://dagster.io/slack. happy dagstering!